# Parametrized generators while using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to give parameters to my generator to use in combination with `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`. For example:

```
def generator(lo, hi):
    for i in range(lo, hi):
        yield float(i)
```

This generator yields floats between `lo` and `hi`. Notice however than when creating a Dataset, these parameters are never passed to this generator.

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, tf.float64)
```

This is because the generator parameter of `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()` should take no arguments.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution based on a functional programming concept called **Partially Applied Functions**. In summary:

> a PAF is a function that takes a function with multiple parameters and returns a function with fewer parameters.

The way I did it is the following:

```
from functools import partial
import tensorflow as tf

def generator(lo, hi):
    for i in range(lo, hi):
        yield float(i)

def get_generator(lo, hi):
    return partial(generator, lo, hi)

tf.data.Dataset(get_generator(lo, hi), tf.float64)
```

The `get_generator(lo, hi)` function returns a partially applied function for the generator which fixes the values for the `lo` and `hi` parameters, which is in fact the parameterless generator required by `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`.

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow `Dataset` already supports parametrizing the generator through the argument `args` which is simply passed to your generator ([see docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#args_35)). Here is a minimal working example tested on TensorFlow `2.0.0`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_train = [i for i in range(0, 20, 2)]  # even
x_val = [i for i in range(1, 20, 2)]  # odd
y_train = [i**2 for i in x_train]  # squared
y_val = [i**2 for i in x_val]

def gen_data_epoch(test=False):  # parametrized generator
    train_data = x_val if test else x_train
    label_data = y_val if test else y_train
    n_tests = len(train_data)
    for test_idx in range(len(train_data)):
        yield train_data[test_idx], label_data[test_idx]

def get_dataset(test=False):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        gen_data_epoch, args=(test,),
        output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32))

print("Train:", [(i[0].numpy(), i[1].numpy()) for i in get_dataset().take(5)])
print("Test: ", [(i[0].numpy(), i[1].numpy()) for i in get_dataset(test=True).take(5)])
```